# Can card types be considered weak entity?

Tags: database, weak-entity

I am trying to do a ER Model for different types of Credit Card.
I have an entity called Credit Card that has a relationship with another entity called Card Type. Would you consider the Card Type entity to be a weak entity? I am not quite sure because, in my opinion, I feel that a Card Type by itself can be a strong entity.

Thank you

Comment: Its strong. A row of cardtype does not rely on a card to exist.

Comment: If you had, say, a card that belongs to a user than that is weak, as it can not exist without the user. But this is not the case here

Comment: Card Type is a strong entity since it can live when no cards for a card type yet exist.